# Swift: Compare generic Types in generic class

Tags: swift, generics, matrix, compiler-errors, operands

I'm creating a Matrix class in swift, which I want it to be Generic, so I can use it Like this:

`let matrix: Matrix<Character>; // Or any other type`

I created my class like this:

`class Matrix<Template>: NSObject {}`

I am crating a function that Apply Gravity to matrix that takes an emptyKey of type Template, and drags every element not equal to emptyKey to the bottom of the matrix

```
// For example emptyKey is "_" and Template is String.

1 _ 2               1 _ _
3 4 5   == To ==>   3 _ 2
6 _ _               6 4 5
```

The problem is: when I am trying to compare the `value` in matrix at a specific location which of type `Template` with the `emptyKey` which also of type `Template`, it fails to compile and gave me the error:

```
Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'Template?' operands
```

I am using `xcode 7.3.1` with `Swift 2.2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to constrain Template to Equatable.

```
class Matrix<Template:Equatable> ...
```

(Also I would advise that you avoid Optionals. I don't know where you're using them, but your error message suggests that you are, and they are going to get in your way.)

Comment: It might help you to read my free online book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_type_constraints